# Read video from file in php

Tags: javascript, php

Good day! I am trying to open video in php but I cant do I dunno where i went wrong

```
$output .= '   
<div class="blog" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="blog-item">
                <div class="row">    
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 blog-content">
                        <h3>'.$row["boshqarma"].'</h3>
                        <video width="100" controls><source src="upload/<?php echo $row['name']?>" type="video/mp4"></video>
                        <p> <h4>'.$row["qisqacha"].'</h4></p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my source code pls help!

Comment: You dont have [src](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_src.asp) attribute in your video tag

Answer (score 0):

1- if use `$output` variable you don't need to echo command 
and `$row['video']` automaticaly printed in your src
2- please print_r($row) and check your `$row['name']` exist or not ?
3- if `$row['name']` exist check this var containe file extension same mp4 ?

Comment: var name exists, the file which i upload is mp4 as well. but video is not playing. Is there any way to play the video?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming that `$row['name']` has the correct video path, so, change this line:

```
<source src="upload/<?php echo $row['name']?>" type="video/mp4">
```

to this:

```
<source src="upload/'.$row["name"].'" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: var_dump() the $row variable to see what's inside. Maybe your browser doesn't support video tag but that seems to be difficult we're in 2018 !